# index.ts is not part of the compilation output

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, compilation

I am trying to compile my Angular application and am getting an error.
It seems to be with the compiler not recognizing the index.ts file. I'm not sure why.

Below is the error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/datatable/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: node_modules\datatable\index.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:629:23)
    at plugin.done.then (node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
 @ ./src/main/ui/app/app.module.ts 13:0-59
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/typeahead/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: node_modules\typeahead\index.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:629:23)
    at plugin.done.then (node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
 @ ./src/main/ui/app/app.module.ts 12:0-59
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the simple fix- Run the following:
npm install --save @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more why you install that specific version?

Comment: There wasn't a specific reason, I found this suggestion on Google. It happened to work for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with ***angular-bootstrap-md\index.ts***

> how I could fix it:
>
> Just put the **index.ts** file to the **tsconfig.jsons include block** ,
>   see below:
>
> ```
> {
>   "compileOnSave": false,
>   "compilerOptions": {
>   "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
>   "sourceMap": true,
>   "declaration": false,
>   "moduleResolution": "node",
>   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
>   "experimentalDecorators": true,
>   "target": "es5",
>   "typeRoots": [
>     "node_modules/@types"
>   ],
>   "lib": [
>     "es2017",
>     "dom"
>   ]  
> },
> "include": [
>   "src/**/*",
>   "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/index.ts"
>   ]
>  }
> ```
>
> Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20091

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix it by installing webpack. That seems to be what I was missing. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify why this is happening in the first place. If published module has typescript files, compiler will try to load those instead of intended compiled javascript files.

This is obviously a mistake in the publish process, as the only ts files should be definition ones (`*.d.ts`).

If these (typeahead and datatable) are your packages, please check your `.npmignore` file. Every .ts file except for .d.ts should be ignored. If they're not yours, please be so kind to report this to the creator/owner.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when the application directory was somewhere under the %users%\Documents directory. After I copied the whole directory into another path (e.g. C:\Data\Angular), the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message too, and for me the cause was a simple typo. I had this line:

```
import { DashboardService } from '../Dashboard.service';
```

The capital D was the cause, changing it into lowercase solved the issue.